# prevent an external event to be dropped on full calendar if earlier than today's date

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using the fullcalendar jquery plugin to create a schedule of events.  I want to prevent the user from dropping an external event on the calendar if it is earlier than current date.
This is my current code:

```
$('#edit_calendar').fullCalendar({
    header:
    {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    titleFormat: { month: 'MMMM' },
    defaultView: 'month',
    droppable: true,
        drop: function (date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {
            //compare today's date with drop date - if in the past, don't allow
            var today = moment().startOf('day');
            var dropDate = moment(date).startOf('day');
            if (dropDate < today)
            {
                //The alert is shown
                alert("An event in the past cannot be added, updated, or deleted.");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {              
                var memberName = $(this).data('event').title;
                var memberID = $(this).attr('id').toString();          
                //Create Event - add to array
                var newEvent = new Object();
                newEvent = {
                    title: memberName,
                    id: memberID,
                    start: date.format(),
                    end: date.format(),
                    objectID: 0
                };
                eventsAdded.push(newEvent);
            }
        },
        ...rest of code
```

If the event is dropped before the current day display the alert and do not create the event.  If shown after the current day, create the event.

In the code above, the alert is shown, but the event is still created.  If the event is dropped after the current day, the event is created.

I thought by adding `return false` after the alert is displayed it will prevent the event from being created.  However, the alert is shown AND the event is created.

Do I have to remove the event or is there a way to prevent the event from being created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to restrict events when they are added or changed using the `selectConstraint` and `eventConstraint` respectively.  However, I would like to add an alert when the user tries to update or add an event outside the start and end dates so they know why it is not working.

This is what I have:

```
$('#edit_calendar').fullCalendar({
    header:
    {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    titleFormat: { month: 'MMMM' },
    defaultView: 'month',
    droppable: true,
        drop: function (date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {     
            var memberName = $(this).data('event').title;
            var memberID = $(this).attr('id').toString();          
            //Create Event - add to array
            var newEvent = new Object();
            newEvent = {
                title: memberName,
                id: memberID,
                start: date.format(),
                end: date.format(),
                objectID: 0
            };
            eventsAdded.push(newEvent);     
        },
        editable: true,
            //The following constraints prevents the user from adding/updating/deleting events that are before the current date
            //The end date is required.  So, you can't add events over a year away from the current date
            eventConstraint: {
                start: moment().startOf('day'),
                end: moment(moment().startOf('day'), 'MM-DD-YYY').add('days', 365)
            },
            selectConstraint: {
                start: moment().startOf('day'),
                end: moment(moment().startOf('day'), 'MM-DD-YYY').add('days', 365)
            },
            ...rest of code...
```

Is there any way I can add an alert when the user tries to add or update an event ou

Comment: Hi, It's a good question. Please post it as a new question and delete this answer. If the previews answer gave you a solution to the original question you can mark the answer as a correct answer. I'll be happy to help you with the new question when posted.

Comment: I will be able to select the above as an answer since it answers the original question.  Here is a link to the new question:  [add alert when adding event outside the constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414485/fullcalendar-add-alert-when-adding-an-event-outside-the-constraints)

Comment: Yes that what I meant, I'm the author of the answer above... :-)

Comment: @Gloria Santin The link to the new question no longer works... I get "Page not found" error.

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/):

> eventDrop does not get called when an external event lands on the calendar. eventReceive is called instead

Having said that, in order to prevent the drop you need to go more back in the chain. You need to use "dropAccept". [You can read about it in the documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/dropAccept/).

Comment: I am not using `eventDrop`.  I am using '`drop`.

Comment: Yes sorry, but the answer still valid. Change 'drop' to 'dropAccept'

Comment: 'drop' function invoke right after 'dropAccept' you can see the chain on the link (top right of the page)

Comment: I don't think `dropAccept` will work in my case.  It is called when I select the external event.  But it does not have a date value at that point.  I take the external event and drag it to to a day.  Only after I drop the event does it have a date that I can check.

Comment: I see, so the last thing I can think of is ['eventConstraint'](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventConstraint/). I didn't use it but you can try...

Comment: Thanks for the tip...I got the calendar to restrict events that are dropped or changed using the `eventContraint` and `selectConstraint`.  Ideally, I would like an alert to display when the user tries to add or change events outside my constraints.  Any ideas?  Below is the code to restrict events...

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'removeEvents' to remove added event.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/removeEvents/

```
drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {

     var add = true;

     ... // Here decide whether to add or not


     if(add){

          ;   
     }
     else{

          //use 'removeEvents' to remove added event
     }
}
```